# Linq - pulling back Parent when item in a Collection has a property that matches a string

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I've got a method that is being passed a `vehicleID` - I need to get all the `SalesChannels` that contain that vehicle.  The `SalesChannels` have an IEnumerable of `SalesChannelVehicle` which have a property called `VehicleID`.

I tried this but it brings back all the `SalesChannels`, not just the one I know my `Vehicle` is in!

```
var queryable = Session.Linq<SalesChannel>();
queryable.Where(y => y.SalesChannelVehicle.Any(z => z.VehicleId == vehicleId));
```

Can anyone assist please?  I'm using NHibernate, though I doubt that makes much difference to this issue.

Comment: You want to modify the `SalesChannel` instances to have different `SalesChannelVehicle` values

Comment: Actually, using an IQueryable provider instead of "IEnumerable Linq" can make a huge difference in how a query must be structured. However, I can find nothing wrong with your query on its face; this should be translated into an Exists clause with a subquery, which probably isn't the most performant solution but should at least return correct results.

Comment: Have you tried using `nhprof` or profiling the database directly to ensure that the `NHibernate to LINQ` translator is working correctly for this particular query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have to assign the returned value to something so have something like;

```
var queryable = Session.Linq<SalesChannel>();
var results = queryable.Where(y => y.SalesChannelVehicle.Any(z => z.VehicleId == vehicleId));
```

**EDIT by KeithS:** The difference between this and the OP is that the `results` variable now contains the IQueryable that includes the Where() method's addition to the expression tree. Simply calling the methods on `queryable` does not update `queryable`'s expression tree in-place; you must assign the extended tree somewhere. If you wanted `queryable` to include the Where() clause, you can simply assign to the same variable:

```
var queryable = Session.Linq<SalesChannel>();
queryable = queryable.Where(y => y.SalesChannelVehicle.Any(z => z.VehicleId == vehicleId));
```

You can also inline the Where() method call:

```
var queryable = Session.Linq<SalesChannel>().Where(y => y.SalesChannelVehicle.Any(z => z.VehicleId == vehicleId));
```

Comment: This. `results` is still an IQueryable, but it has the extra expression tree structure created by the Where() method. Obviously to evaluate the tree you need a ToList() or similar method.

Comment: Thanks for putting me right - bit of a school boy error there - forgot to do queryable = queryable(Where Clause)!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var results =
    from channel in Session.Linq<SalesChannel>()
    from vehicle in channel.SalesChannelVehicle
    where vehicle.VehicleId == vehicleId
    select channel;
```

(assuming each vehicle appears only 1 time in SalesChannelVehicle)